# How to remove "Load Report Failed" Error in Crystal Report Runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports Runtime 13.0.5 on my client's PCs for bill printing in my WinForms application. Everything was going good until some of my clients started facing problems.

After a full day of report generating/printing, in the evening,s Crystal Reports starts giving the error "Load Report Failed" every time I generate report.

It came to my notice that my clients generate hundreds of reports in a day and the CR runtime generates temporary files in temp folder each time it generates bill. Maybe those hundreds of all day temporary files puts a load on the CR runtime and causes it to give this error in the evening.

Closing the application and deleting all temporary files from the folder allows the CR runtime to start working again. I also increased the maximum job limit for Crystal Reports to 1000 from 75 in the registry.

But, I can't tell all of my clients to close the application, delete all the temporary files, and then use the application again. I need a permanent solution for this problem.

Or, if there isn't any permanent solution, is there a way to delete temporary files after each report generation?

**Edit:**
I tried disposing report but no success. I am showing report dialog from main form and setting data source on report viewer form. If I dispose my report before showing report viewer window I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Attaching Code for better understanding.

**On main form:**

```
if (str1 == "A4Printer")
{
     Frm_ReportViewer _objfrm_ReportViewer = new Frm_ReportViewer();
     DataTable dtDetailsReport = _objCommon.DataGridView2DataTable(dgv_SaleForm, "table");
     SendData _obj = new SendData(_objfrm_ReportViewer.ReceiveSalesDataA4);
     _obj(dtDetailsReport, txt_BillNo.Text, accno, txt_PaidAmount.Text, txt_Balence.Text, txt_TotalAmount.Text, txtdisc.Text);
     _objfrm_ReportViewer.ShowDialog();
     ClearSale();
     MasterClear();
     cmb_CustomerName.Select();
}
```

**On Report Viewer Form:**

```
public void ReceiveSalesDataA4(DataTable dtDetail, string BillNO, string AccNo, string PaidAmount, string Balance, string TotalAmount, string Disc)
{
    CrystalReport.Crt_SaleBill _objReport = new CrystalReport.Crt_SaleBill();
    string CompanyMaster = "SELECT tbl_CompanyMaster.CompanyName, tbl_CompanyMaster.Addressline1, tbl_CompanyMaster.Addressline2, tbl_CompanyMaster.MobileNo1, tbl_CompanyMaster.MobileNo2, tbl_CompanyMaster.Landlineno, tbl_CompanyMaster.VatNo, tbl_CompanyMaster.Tinno FROM tbl_CompanyMaster";
    string CustomerMaster = "SELECT CustomerName,AccNo,Address,PhoneNo,Dat FROM tbl_CustomerMaster WHERE (AccNo = '" + AccNo + "')";

    DataTable dt_CustomerMaster = _objSQLHelper.GetDataTable(CustomerMaster);
    _objReport.Database.Tables["dt_registration"].SetDataSource(dt_registration);
    _objReport.Database.Tables["dt_SalesThermalReport"].SetDataSource(dtDetail);
    _objReport.Database.Tables["dt_CustomerMaster"].SetDataSource(dt_CustomerMaster);
    _objReport.SetParameterValue("BillNo", BillNO);
    _objReport.SetParameterValue("PaidAmount", PaidAmount);
    _objReport.SetParameterValue("Disc", Disc);
    _objReport.SetParameterValue("Balance", Balance);
    _objReport.SetParameterValue("TotalAmount", TotalAmount);

    _objReport.SetParameterValue("cdt", clsVariable.CDate);

    Crt_ReportViewer.ReportSource = _objReport;

}
```

If I put `_objReport.Dispose();` after `Crt_ReportViewer.ReportSource = _objReport;` above, 
on main form `_objfrm_ReportViewer.ShowDialog();` gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". So, I can't dispose it here. I am looking for another solution. I apologize for any mistake, I am new to Crystal Report, and this problem is too important for my company as clients are annoyed because of "Load Report Failed" Error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Moderator note to prospective close-voters:** Crystal Reports falls into the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers" and is therefore on-topic, as per the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete any temporary files to solve this. This problem occurs when you create a new instance of the report every time that you want to use it and don't dispose it.

Consider the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        CrystalReport1 myReport = new CrystalReport1();
        myReport.SetDataSource(MyDataSet);
    }
}
```

This most probably will generate the "Load Report Failed" error after some iterations. To solve this, just dispose the report when you no longer need it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        CrystalReport1 myReport = new CrystalReport1();
        myReport.SetDataSource(MyDataSet);
        //
        //Some code here
        //
        myReport.Dispose();
    }
}
```

A better solution is to declare the report variable only once. This will also make the code run faster.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrystalReport1 myReport = new CrystalReport1();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        myReport.SetDataSource(MyDataSet);
    }

    myReport.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but its not working for me. I have added some info and coding in question. Please go through it. Thanks a lot again.